# How to NOT reload component Angular

Tags: angular, reload

I have in app.component.html the layout for a side menu which englobes the real content of my app.

When I visit a link to get to a different page, I'd like that only the content of my app is reloaded, not the entire thing. For two reasons, one, the visual delay which makes the app seem slow, and two, it would be much easier for me to display the currently selected menu.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You have to use routing for this.

Basically, your app.component.html will contain these lines

```
<app-header></app-header>           // This will render the header component
<router-outlet></router-outlet>     // This will render all the route changes
<app-footer></app-footer>           // This will render the footer
```

> Working Examples: Header and Footer don't reload, even the tabs selected are highlighted

[My Portfolio](http://www.abhijit-kar.com/)
[Angular Scaffolding](http://www.abhijit-kar.com/angular-scaffolding/home)    // Take a look at this, you can even have a look at the code of how it works. Fork it all you want.

> Reference

Angular Routing is a fairly large topic, deserving a whole page.

Take a look how it works: [Angular.io](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) Documentation

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed! 
Now as a side effect I have some API calls that aren't being rendered but I'll figure it out ^^

Comment: @JoaoVentura That's the spirit, anyways we are here to help!